# linux noob: where can I find packages for my version?

Tags: linux, redhat

Hi I have inherited a new server running

Linux version 2.6.18-128.2.1.el5
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704
Red Hat 4.1.2-44

basically I need to install an ftp server on it, apache, some extensions..

where can i find software for this specific version?  everything i download doesn't even install properly.  I can't use the rpm command because of firewall restrictions.

edit: oh its quad 2.8 xeon 64-bit... maybe that is the issue

Thanks,
linux noob

Answer (score 4):

You can try http://apt.sw.be/redhat/ or directly from the product site that you're looking for. Apache has pre-built RPMs for example.

edit: Can you talk to whoever is in charge of your firewall and have them allow yum? That's pretty standard

Comment: +1 for trying to get the firewall changed.

Answer (score 3):

RPM uses standard HTTP to fetch the packages, so if you can surf the web, you ought to be able to download packages.

Since this is a RHEL5 box, yum is the preferred package manager. Some common commands are:

**yum update** : Update your system with the latest packages and kernel.

**yum search *keyword*** : Search for a package whose description contains the keyword you specify.

**yum install *name-of-package*** : Once you find a package you want, install it with this command.

For example, the FTP server is called vsftpd. To install it, type:

```
yum install vsftpd
```

You'll need to be root to do any of the commands that make changes to the system.

Comment: I may be missing something but how did you determine that he's running rhel5? If he's on rhel4 yum will need to be installed and configured.

Comment: His kernel version is "2.6.18-128.2.1.el5" The "el5" stands for Enterprise Linux 5.

Comment: ahh! got it. totally missed that and I read it threes times. :)

Answer (score -1):

If it is RHEL4 you will need to look into the up2date command.  RHEL5 uses yum.

Use caution with FTP clear text passwords etc.  In RedHat servers they use httpd as the name instead of apache.

To answer your question on RHEL4:  up2date -i httpd vsftpd

Man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/up2date